# Cold Fusion Close File cfscript

Tags: cfml, coldfusion-11

This should be simple, but how do I close and release the file opened with this

```
<cfscript>
    FileName="C:\category1.txt";
    FileIOClass=createObject("java","java.io.FileReader");
    FileIO=FileIOClass.init(FileName);
    LineIOClass=createObject("java","java.io.BufferedReader" );
    LineIO=LineIOClass.init(FileIO);
</cfscript>
<cffile action = "delete" file = "C:\category1.txt">
```

**ColdFusion could not delete the file C:\category1.txt for an unknown reason**

Comment: Did you try `LineIOClass.close(); FileIO.close();` Before delete?

Comment: I tried several things "similar", but that totally did the trick. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Is there a reason why you use Java functionality instead of the ColdFusion internal `<cffile action="read">`?

Comment: All the processes I write use cfffile/read, but this one was written for me by a subcontractor several years ago. I don't know why he used this method, so it wasn't familiar to me. The file being left open has bedeviled me for a while.

Comment: FWIW, you only need to close the BufferedReader which closes the FileReader for you